# What are the list of Windows Services needed for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, windows-server

What are the Windows Services that needs to be running for SharePoint 2013 ?

Like

- SharePoint Administration
- SharePoint Timer Services
- SQLServer

Can anyone provide a complete list of mandatory services for running SharePoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 4):

#### SharePoint Server 2013 Windows Services

- Document Conversions Launcher for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (DCLauncher15)
- Document Conversions Load Balancer for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (DCLoadBalancer15)
- SharePoint Server Search 15 (OSearch15)
- SharePoint Administration (SPAdminV4)
- SharePoint Search Host Controller (SPSearchHostController)
- SharePoint Timer Service (SPTimerV4)
- SharePoint Tracing Service (SPTraceV4)
- SharePoint User Code Host (SPUserCodeV4)
- SharePoint VSS Writer (SPWriterV4)
- AppFabric Caching Service (AppFabricCachingService)
- World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)

Answer (score 1):

Hi This is list of required windows services for SharePoint

•   SharePoint Administration

•   SharePoint Timer

•   SharePoint Tracing

•   SharePoint User Code Host

•   SharePoint VSS Writer

•   World Wide Web Publishing Service

•   SharePoint Server Search

Answer (score 0):

Can SharePoint Administration service run under "Local system" account??

**Notes**: I am trying to upgrade from SP2016 STD to SP2016 ENT and running to lot off troubles descripted here:

[Does uppgrading from SharePoint server 2013 Standard to SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise require reinstall?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0632ee22-ca0e-4c3e-b300-ffafa35aa1d8/does-uppgrading-from-sharepoint-server-2013-standard-to-sharepoint-server-2013-enterprise-require).

And finally found possible solution here:

[How To: Convert SharePoint Standard License To Enterprise License In SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Convert-SharePoint-standard-license-to-Enterprise-license-in-SharePoint-2010).

Comment: Is it the answer or are you asking any question?

Comment: It is question,.. If SharePoint administration service should run under Local system acc or can run under other domain acc (with particular permissions). Update: Acctually when I changed it to other domain, Upgrade started, but now Iam run into issues, when Timer service "terminated unexpectedly"... Thanks